# bottle.py server deployment

Tags: python, https, web, bottle

I am moving from development to deployment and wonder how can i make my bottle.py application service both HTTP and HTTPS requests, and be multiprocess/multithreaded? I understand I need to use something like cherrypy instead of wsgiref?

Answer (score 1):

In the [Docs](http://bottlepy.org/docs/stable/tutorial.html#deployment) there are ideas to increase performance and multi-thread. I use a different folder and port for the deployed version so I can test without disrupting use.

The long text is [here](http://bottlepy.org/docs/stable/deployment.html#deployment) and includes pasteserver, and several others.